# ATI drivers incompatible with xorg

Tags: drivers, ati, xorg, radeon

some of you are having problems with ati driver? I have a Radeon
R7 240  and It Seems That the drivers are no more compatible with the xorg server I'm using...what can I do?

I'm on the last release of ubuntu studio I tried installing that but it screwed my xorg.
http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Ubuntu%20x86%2064

Then I tried There
 http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/latest-linux-beta-driver.aspx
but the installation stop and gives me that error

```
error: Detected X Server version 'XServer 1.17.1_64a' is not supported. Supported versions are X.Org 6.9 or later, up to XServer 1.10 (default:v2:x86_64:lib:XServer 1.17.1_64a:none:3.19.0-25-lowlatency:)
Installation will not proceed.
```

Comment: Where did you try to install the drivers for your card from (website or Additional Drivers app)? What Ubuntu version are you on? What happens when you try to install the drivers? Does the installation fail, or is there some problem afterward? Please answer these questions by ___[edit]ing___ your question.